# Highchart colorValue` = color must be a symbol or a string, not a formul

Tags: highcharts

I want to replicate the code in the [DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/data-visualization-highcharter-r), however, it raises such an error:Error: `colorValue` = color must be a symbol or a string, not a formula
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

My code is as follows:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 library(highcharter)

pokemon%>%
   count(type_1)%>%
   arrange(n)%>%
   hchart(type = "treemap", 
   hcaes(x = type_1, value = n,
   color = n))
```

-----updated 5 April 2019 ----

After I update all my packages, the code works well, maybe the packages before are too old for the new R version.

Jim

Comment: This code is working fine in my environment and displays treemap as expected (same graph like in the link you provided). Do you have any specific questions? Did you install both tidyverse and highcharter packages?

Comment: Yes. Both packages are installed. The sessioninfo:R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.4  

other attached packages:
 [1] broom_0.4.4       moderndive_0.2.0  bindrcpp_0.2.2   
 [4] highcharter_0.7.0 forcats_0.3.0     stringr_1.3.0    
 [7] dplyr_0.7.4       purrr_0.2.4       readr_1.1.1      
[10] tidyr_0.8.0       tibble_1.4.2      ggplot2_2.2.1    
[13] tidyverse_1.2.1

Comment: I'm still not able to reproduce your issue. In my environment (Windows 10) it's working fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe I should try to reinstall R and all the specific packages.

Comment: After I update all my packages, the code works well. So  this topic should be closed.@ raf18seb Thanks for your feedback again!

Comment: I didn't actually do anything, but I'm glad that I could point you to the right direction ;) you're welcome!